# How to insert Multidimensional array into Database - Using laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            ['service_id'] => 5bb707ce2c75d216e9383513
            ['service_quantity'] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            ['service_id'] => 5bb707ff2c75d2116253f6b6
            ['service_quantity'] => 2
        )

)
```

How to insert value in Database using laravel. facing problem in foreach loop.

Comment: Iterate over array and insert.

Comment: what is the problem you face in using `foreach` can you include it in your question?

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin Thanks for reply. foreach($data as $service){
            echo "my result" . $service->service_id; 
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your data array keys matches exactly with the table column names.
you can do as simple as this.

```
Db::table('your_table_name')
    ->insert(your_array);
```

Comment: In above  array,  i'm unable to get valaue of 'service_id' and 'servicce_quantity', bcause when i use foreach value getting again in array for plz help me for getting value of all key in loop

Comment: you can't access index of array like `$service->service_id;`. it should be `$service['service_id'];`

Comment: Getting "message": "Undefined index: service_id", error foreach($data3 as $service){
                echo $service['service_id'];
                echo $service['service_quantity']; }

Comment: My array in this form and i wnat to insert all array data one-by -one in DB by Db::table('your_table_name')
    ->insert(your_array);
$data = Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            ['service_id'] => 1234
            ['service_quantity'] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            ['service_id'] => 45678
            ['service_quantity'] => 10
        )

);

foreach($data as $service){
                echo $service['service_id'];
                echo $service['service_quantity'];            
               
                }

Comment: I understand the problem, But your array is not properly formatted, how did you get this array, their is where we need to find a solution.